# How can I configure different cloud providers on dockerfile-maven plugin

Tags: dockerfile, spotify-docker-client, dockerfile-maven-plugin

How can I configure different cloud providers (for GCP, AWS, Azure) on https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven maven plugin, so that it seamlessly enables deployment on all cloud providers. We want maven deploy command to deploy to all cloud providers (say GCP, Azure, AWS). How can we specify configuration for all of them, but have the flexibility to deploy to a cloud provider when needed

Comment: Make use of maven profile by wrapping your expected plugins to control your deployment with your expected cloud. Please take a look on [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) documentation.

Comment: Do you want to add AWS, Azure and GCP in Single file? Add all of them in one single file. We can use the `appengine:deploy` command to deploy configuration files, such as `cron.yaml`, `dispatch.yaml`, and `index.yaml`. Please go Throw [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) and [Configration](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#configuration).